# TSQL - Having Clause error when trying to perform an aggregate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a script with some hardcoded values.  I've been tasked with putting the hardcoded values into a table so the script can run even if the table values change. Instead of looking for a specific value, I'm trying to check it against a table.  I have an example of the working code prior to the change and non-working code trying to sue the same logic.

I get this error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Working code:

```
HAVING SUM (CASE WHEN Keyword = 1313 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Non-working Code:

```
HAVING SUM (CASE WHEN Keyword IN (SELECT Keyword FROM TableB) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

I don't understand how to account for the table change, I am not understanding something.  What do I seem to be missing about this issue and how can I get this to work?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to compute `CASE WHEN Keyword IN (SELECT Keyword FROM TableB) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` inside a sub-query before you aggregate.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't let you have a sub-query inside of an aggregate.

See the master, Pinal Dave: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/16/sql-server-fix-error-130-cannot-perform-an-aggregate-function-on-an-expression-containing-an-aggregate-or-a-subquery/

This would be a solution:

```
SELECT
    SUM(MyField)
FROM (
    SELECT
      CASE WHEN Keyword IN (SELECT Keyword FROM TableB) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as MyField
    FROM YourTable
    ) subquery
HAVING SUM(MyField) = 0
```

Edit: (improvement from Dale K comment)

Comment: Or just use a sub-query, no need for the overhead of a temp table.

Comment: Yes that is better.  I changed the answer to that.

Comment: My preferred method is `CROSS APPLY` then you only need to subquery that bit, not the whole thing